# What is a constant field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, differential-algebra

I am looking at the following:

[image]

[image]

Could you explain to me what a constant field is?

$$$$

P.S. I found this in the paper of T. Honda, "Algebraic differential equation" (pages 170-176).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "constant" here is being used in the sense of those elements of $k((x))$ whose differential is zero.  Note that in addition to elements $\alpha \in k$, we have power series whose terms have exponents of $x$ that are multiples of $p$ (since this is a finite characteristic of the underlying base field $k$), and by the chain rule, the quotients of two such (nonzero) power series.

The Remark at the bottom of your image has to do with the fact that a reciprocal of a power series $\sum \alpha_i x^i$ in $k[[x]]$ exists in $k[[x]]$ if and only if $\alpha_0 \in k$ is nonzero.

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-) $$$$ So does the 
the part: "If $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$, then $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has also a solution $y_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$." at 

[http://i.stack.imgur.com/FzpGZ.png] [http://i.stack.imgur.com/lPf2H.png] 

because of the following?

Comment: We suppose that $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$. 
The constant field of $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$ is $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x^p)$. 
So if we multiply the equation by a suitable constant, it follows that $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution also in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$.

Comment: That seems to be the basic idea, though with the introduction of new notation, one should be wary of subtleties to be checked.  I don't feel I'm getting the whole "picture" from the fragments of the text images.  Now that you have some experience with MathJax and $\LaTeX$, I recommend using it in your questions.  In this particular Question it would be an improvement to cite the book or paper which is at issue, and where the discussion occurs in that work.

Comment: Which new notation do you mean? $$$$ I found this in the paper of T. Honda, "Algebraic differential equation".

Comment: I mean that $\overline K_\mathfrak{p} (x)$ is not defined in your original Question, nor am I confident of its interpretation from the additional images posted in your comments.  Please edit the Question to include the citation given in your comment above, and what journal and page number a Reader would need to locate the passage.

Comment: I added the citation in my original post... The second image of comment above is a part of the proof of the theorem [http://i.stack.imgur.com/rqLw0.png] for $n=1$.

Answer (score 3):

The field of constants of a differential field is the subfield of elements a with $∂a=0$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentially_closed_field).

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-) $$$$ So does the 
the part: "If $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$, then $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has also a solution $y_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$." at 

[http://i.stack.imgur.com/FzpGZ.png] [http://i.stack.imgur.com/lPf2H.png] 

because of the following?

Comment: We suppose that $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$. 
The constant field of $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$ is $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x^p)$. 
So if we multiply the equation by a suitable constant, it follows that $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution also in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$.